# dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 troubles

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I currently have three drives:

1. 120 GB SSD with ubuntu 14.04
2. 2TB WD with windows 10
3. 1TB hitachi with pictures and files.

What I would like to do is dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubunutu - with the GRUB window. The thing is when all three drives are connected to the tower, nothing boots. I call see all HDD in BIOS. Separately, the ssd goes right into Ubuntu - disconnect that, connect the 2TB and that goes into windows - showing that everything works fine. I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Computer Specs:

```
Antec Sonata III Case with 500W Power Supply
ASUS P7P55D-E Pro ATX Intel Motherboard
EVGA GeForce 9500 GT 01G-P3-N959-TR Video Card
Intel Core i7-860 2.8GHz LGA 1156 95W Quad-Core Processor
G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 4GB (2 x 2GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory x 2 (for a total of 8GB)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know on which hard drive your /boot partition is ? It must be your primary boot devices set in BIOS.

Then under Ubuntu try to do

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will detect all your bootable devices and create the grub menu that will allow you to choose your OS during boot.

[image]

Comment: this is what I get when I run the command
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf

Comment: Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin

Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sdb1

done

Comment: So it detect your windows partition, Now make sure that your bios boot on your ubuntu disk.

Comment: @Kguat You are the man!! I ran the command, rebooted my computer and now it prompts me which OS to boot into. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I helped, don't hesitate to mark your question as answered.